# Correct usage of SetRootType in FlatBuffers

Tags: flatbuffers

I'm trying to set a new custom root before parsing a JSon into a structure via flatbuffers.

The Corresponding FSB has a root_type already and I want to override it only to be able to parse it into a struct once.

The SetRootType("NonRootStructInFbsT") fails

The documentation of the API says, this can be used to override the current root which is exactly what I want to do.

```
  std::string schemaText;
  std::string schemaFile("MySchema.fbs");
  if(not flatbuffers::FileExists(schemaFile.c_str())) {
    error("Schema file inaccessible: ", schemaFile);
    return nullptr;
  }
  if(not flatbuffers::LoadFile(schemaFile.c_str(), false, &schemaText))       {
    error(TAG, "Failed to load schema file: ", schemaFile);
    return nullptr;
  }
  info("Read schema file: ", schemaText.size(), schemaText);

  flatbuffers::Parser parser;
  if(not parser.SetRootType("NonRootStructInFbsT")) {
    error("Unable to set root type: ", customRoot);
      return nullptr;
  }
  info("Set the root type: ", customRoot);
```

I always get the error message 
Unable to set root type: NonRootStructInFbsT

Answer (score 1):

The root of a FlatBuffer can only be a `table`, so `root_type` and `SetRootType` will reject names of anything else, like a `struct` or a `union`.

Furthermore, the fact that the name ends in `T` appears to refer to an "object API" type. These are names purely in the generated code, you need to supply names as they are in the schema.

Answer (score 1):

The posted code lacks call of `flatbuffers::Parser::Parse` with schema contents. Your code:

```cpp
    std::string schemaText;
    std::string schemaFile("MySchema.fbs");
    if(not flatbuffers::FileExists(schemaFile.c_str())) {
        error("Schema file inaccessible: ", schemaFile);
        return nullptr;
    }
    if(not flatbuffers::LoadFile(schemaFile.c_str(), false, &schemaText)) {
        error(TAG, "Failed to load schema file: ", schemaFile);
        return nullptr;
    }
    info("Read schema file: ", schemaText.size(), schemaText);

    flatbuffers::Parser parser;
```

It is all OK, but here we have contents of schema file in `schemaText` and empty `parser` with default options. Too early to set root types. We should read the schema to `parser` with something like:

```cpp
    if(not parser.Parse(schemaText)) { 
        error(TAG, "Defective schema: ", parser.error_);
        return nullptr;
    }
```

After that if we reached here we have `parser` with schema and so in that schema we can chose also root type:

```cpp
    if(not parser.SetRootType("NonRootStructInFbsT")) {
        error("Unable to set root type: ", customRoot);
        return nullptr;
    }
    info("Set the root type: ", customRoot);
```

Note that `parser.error_` is quite informative about any errors you face during `parser` usage.